# Scroll to the object in my NGUI ScrollView with c#

Tags: c#, uiscrollview, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am trying to create a chat and it works ok except when there are more posts than can fit in the view. So when I open the scrollview it always start at the top, but the latest chat is at the bottom and I should be starting there. I have the same problem when I add an post it instantiates below my viewport?!? How do I solve this?

I am trying to do so with a SpringPanel but am having a hard time figuring out what to put into it?

```
SpringPanel mySpringPanel.Begin(GameObject go, Vector3 pos, float strength)
```

I know the strength and the Vector3 should be something like(0,MyLatsObject,0) but what is the gameobject and again... How do I figure out the Vector3?

Hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [CentreOnChild](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_center_on_child.html) script. With it you can call `UICenterOnChild.CenterOn(Transform target)`
to centre the scrollview on the gameObject you want.